# How to inject html into component using angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

i want to inject some html into my component(Angular 2),i used to use $compile in angularjs to inject html into the DOM, because in my injected html i have a method doesnt execute heres the code :

```
addTextField(){
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + this.counter);

      newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ this.counter + ' : </label>' +
  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + this.counter +
  '" id="textbox' + this.counter + '" value="" >'+'<span 
   (click)="removeTextField(this.counter)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-
    right" style="z-index:33;cursor: pointer">  </span>');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
}
```

removeTextField function :

```
removeTextField(currentTextField){
  alert(currentTextField);
}
```

when i try to add a textfield dyanamically it has a delete span with it i mean  (click)="removeTextField(this.counter)" as mentioned in the code, but the problem when i tried to click this span its execute nothing the function doesnt fired..any help please

Comment: Do you need it in angular way not in jquery correct?

Comment: yess angular 2...what i want is , the function executes thats all

Comment: You're looking for `ngIf` and `[innerHTML]`

Comment: no..the code above works fine..but removeTextField method doesnt execute

Answer (score 0):

Here we have give templateUrl where HTML will get from the given path.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup , Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    results:any;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    images: any[];

        ngOnInit() {

         this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all').subscribe(data => {
         debugger;
          // Read the result field from the JSON response.
          this.results = data;
        });

        }


    }
```